# Newsletter opinion poll

Tags: php, newsletter

Is it possible to include an opinion poll in a newsletter. For e.g something like

```
Do you like stackoverflow?
Yes option
No option
Don't know option
Then a submit button.
```

Usually if you have lot of HTML in a newsletter it tends to go to junk mail. But would like to know on the possibilities.

Comment: Why don't you make it as links instead? Mails with a form have a very high chance of being flagged as spam, and even if they don't there's always the possibility they won't be working right. Make a couple links with a parameter (something like poll.php?pollid=12345&option=yes) and get the answers on your server. Personally, I won't ever,ever, use a form in an email I received

Comment: @Damien, sounds good. Thank you. I added an image of the question above and clicking on the image(anywhere) takes the user to our server with the actual poll form.